# Obtain a list of views under certain CGPoint

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I need to get a list of views that are on certain CGPoint. Using this method:

```
- (void)handlePan:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    UIView *subview = [recognizer.view hitTest:[recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view] withEvent:nil];
    //....
 }
```

gives me only 1 view. Is there any way to get an array of views under the location?

Comment: You just need to recurse with the subview that you get back until you get nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *subviewsList = [NSMutableArray new];
for (UIView *subview in self.view.subviews) {
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, point) ) {
        [subviewsList addObject:subview];
    }
}
```

`point` is your `[recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view]`. Assuming, of course, you are running this code inside a viewController.